# pn532 on Rpi4 SPI reading NFC NDEF message from mobile phone emulating type 4 card

Tags: python, android, raspberry-pi4, ndef, pn532

Hi I am working on a project that requires the pn532 to read an NDEF message from an android device and the internet doesn't seem to have much examples on how to get it to work. The device is using an NDEF tag emulator app for testing. Its reading the Ids but not the payload. what am I doing wrong?

the key block of code that should do it is :
"..ndef_data = pn532.ntag2xx_read_block(4)"
but nothing shows up after the Id.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.